# Difference between Servlet and JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between JSF, Servlet and JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095397/what-is-the-difference-between-jsf-servlet-and-jsp)

What is the Exact difference between the Servlet And JSP

Answer (score 6):

A JSP is a special kind of Servlet that is edited in a HTML-like syntax and compiled into Servlet byte code by a web container (usually at deploy-time or when first accessed).

JSPs *can* contain complex Java code, however that has been considered a bad practice for the last 8 years or so, so JSPs will usually only contain

- HTML
- [Custom Tags](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/JSPTags.html)
- [Expression Language](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html)

(Judging by the age of the above links you can tell that JSP is not exactly cutting-edge anymore)

Answer (score 2):

JSP is a template language that the servlet/JSP engine compiles into a servlet, which is then compiled into Java byte code and executed.

Think of JSP as a convenient HTML factory.

Answer (score 1):

Simply, Servlet is Java code that outputs HTML. JSP is the opposite, it's HTML that has Java code inside tags.